# Cyclic coordinates and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral

Consider a classical system described by a Lagrangian $L(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, a function of $n$ coordinates.

In a classical context, if a coordinate is cyclic, that means that a certain quantity is conserved through the time evolution of the system. One immediately sees it, supposing $x_1$ is cyclic and using the Euler-Lagrange equations:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} L}{\mathrm{d} x_1} = 0 = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \frac{\mathrm{d} L}{\mathrm{d} \dot{x_1}}
$$

implying that $p_{x_1} = \mathrm{d} L / \mathrm{d} \dot{x_1}$ is a conserved quantity. That effectively reduces the dimensionality of the problem by one.

Now consider the quantized version, using the path integral formalism for calculating the transition amplitude between two quantum states one has

$$
\int \mathcal{D} x_1 \cdots \mathcal{D} x_n e^{\mathrm{i} \int \mathrm{d}^n x \ L /\hbar}
$$

and all configurations are explored, with varying probability, so $p_{x_1}$ is no longer classically conserved (i.e. it is no longer a constant). However $p_{x_1}$ is conserved on the classical trajectory, w.r.t. which the quantum fluctuations cancel out.

My question is: is it still possible to use the cyclic coordinate to simplify the problem, or (better!) to reduce its dimensionality at a quantum level?

Comment: What do you mean *"$p_{x_1}$ is no longer conserved"*. Since classically we have $\{p_1,H\} = 0$ for the cyclic coordinate, we also have $[p_1,H] = 0$ in the quantum theory, and $p_1$ is still conserved in all senses in which "conservation" has meaning in quantum mechanics.

Comment: What I meant is  "$p_{x_1}$ is no longer classically conserved", in other words it is no longer a constant. Of course it commutes with the Hamiltonian, but it is not clear to me if it can be used to reduce the dimensionality of the problem, like in the classical case. Or even if it can be used to simplify the problem in some other way.

I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Hello zakk, I love this question! In his textbook "Gauge fields and strings", Polyakov argues that there is a general rule: cyclic fields in path integrals can be always integrated out by taking them to their classical values, as dictated by the equations of motion. This can be justified by considering a "propagator" of these fields which is ultralocal and thus does not influence the long-range behaviour. However, I am unaware if there is a corresponding well-formulated mathematical theorem and if there are limitations to it.

Comment: On second thoughts, I might just have misinterpreted the question. Could you please elaborate on what you consider to be a "cyclic coordinate"? Also isn't there a mistake in the E/L equation? The correct equation is $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_1} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_1}$. Anyways, I was talking about coordinates for which the Lagrangian is independent of the *derivative*. Probably not what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error! I was talking about coordinates for which the Lagrangian is independent of the derivative, too! I just got that equation wrong, sorry, not I corrected it. 

I just got Polyakov's book, do you remember the chapter?

Comment: Chapter 9 "Quantum strings and random surfaces", paragraph 9.1. He talks about the "law of the large numbers", that is exactly what you were asking if I am not mistaken.

Comment: But please note that: 1. cyclic coordinates are those for which the Lagrangian is only dependent on the derivative (and not on the value of the coordinate itself) - so your question uses bad terminology. 2. For cyclic coordinates there is indeed a conserved momentum, whereas for coordinates which only enter the Lagrangian without derivatives (the ones which you are interested in), the conjugate momentum is *zero by definition*!

Comment: Thanks! Btw I was asking about cyclic coordinates, in the usual meaning of the term, I just got the equation wrong. Now I corrected it!

Comment: If you were talking about the usual definition, then my answer isn't of any help to you, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Nevermind! Thanks for reading my question and providing a nice pointer!